# C# EF CF - Referential integrity constraint violation: Multiplue foreign keys to same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I'm having issues updating entities when referencing the same table multiple times in the one entity.

I have two Classes `User` and `Expense`. `Expense` is referencing to the `User` multiple times:

- `User` - Who lodged the Expense
- `ApprovedUser` - Who approved
- `ProcessedUser` - Who processed
- `ModifiedUser` - Who modified the Expense

```cs
    public class User
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// User Id
        /// </summary>
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Display Name
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Display Name")]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Expense
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// User Id
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User Id")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Linked User
        /// </summary>
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public User User { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Approved User Id
        /// </summary>
        [Display(Name = "Approved User Id")]
        public string ApprovedUserId { get; set; } = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Linked Approve User
        /// </summary>
        [ForeignKey("ApprovedUserId")]
        public User ApprovedUser { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Processed User Id
        /// </summary>
        [Display(Name = "Processed User Id")]
        public string ProcessedUserId { get; set; } = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Linked Processed User
        /// </summary>
        [ForeignKey("ProcessedUserId")]
        public User ProcessedUser { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Modified User Id
        /// </summary>
        [Display(Name = "Modified By User Id")]
        public string ModifiedByUserId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Linked Modified User
        /// </summary>
        [ForeignKey("ModifiedByUserId")]
        public User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

When i update the field `ModifiedByUserId` i get this: 
`A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'User.Id' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'Expense.ModifiedByUserId' on the other end.`

However if i null the `ModifiedByUserId` it updates as normal.
I have also tried to null the `ModifiedBy` and set the `ModifiedByUserId` with the same result.

I've looked at multiple SO posts and spent 12 hours trying to figure out what seems like something that should be so simple but i and can't find anything that's worked.

(I'd prefer to stay away from fluent api if possible.)

**Example**

Bob and Jim are in the `User` table and then there's a `Expense` Bod originally Modified the `Expense` so `ModifiedByUserId` is set to Bob's `User.Id`. I've now edited the `Expense` so the `ModifiedByUserId` should now be my `User.Id`. Nothing changes in the `User`, just the `Expense`

**Generated SQL**

```sql
create table [dbo].[Expense] (
    [Id] [int] not null identity,
    [SubmittedDate] [datetime2](7) not null,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) not null,
    [ApprovedUserId] [nvarchar](128) null,
    [ProcessedUserId] [nvarchar](128) null,
    [State] [int] not null,
    [ModifiedByUserId] [nvarchar](128) null,
    [LastNotification] [datetime2](7) not null,
    [NextNotification] [datetime2](7) not null,
    [NumberOfNotifications] [int] not null,
    [StopNotifications] [bit] not null,
    [Inserted] [datetime2](7) not null,
    [Updated] [datetime2](7) not null,
    [Deleted] [bit] not null,
    primary key ([Id])
);

create table [dbo].[User] (
    [Id] [nvarchar](128) not null,
    [DisplayName] [nvarchar](max) not null,
    [Department] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [JobTitle] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [Email] [nvarchar](max) not null,
    [TelephoneNumber] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [MobileNumber] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [DownloadedProfileImg] [bit] not null,
    [ManagerId] [nvarchar](128) null,
    [Deleted] [bit] not null,
    primary key ([Id])
);

alter table [dbo].[Expense] add constraint [Expense_ApprovedUser] foreign key ([ApprovedUserId]) references [dbo].[User]([Id]);
alter table [dbo].[Expense] add constraint [Expense_ModifiedBy] foreign key ([ModifiedByUserId]) references [dbo].[User]([Id]);
alter table [dbo].[Expense] add constraint [Expense_ProcessedUser] foreign key ([ProcessedUserId]) references [dbo].[User]([Id]);
alter table [dbo].[Expense] add constraint [Expense_User] foreign key ([UserId]) references [dbo].[User]([Id]);
alter table [dbo].[User] add constraint [User_Manager] foreign key ([ManagerId]) references [dbo].[User]([Id]);
```

*Code*

```cs
var expense = await ExpenseService.GetExpense(4);
expense.Updated = DateTime.Now;
expense.ModifiedByUserId = "user_id_string";
await ExpenseService.Update(expense);
```

GetExpense

```cs
        public async Task<Expense> GetExpense(int? id)
        {
            var expense = await Expenses.Query()
                .Include(x => x.User)
                .Include(x => x.ModifiedBy)
                .Include(x => x.ApprovedUser)
                .Include(x => x.ProcessedUser)
                .FirstAsync(x => x.Id == id);

            return expense;
        }
```

Update Expense:

```cs
        public async Task<Expense> Update(Expense expense)
        {
            Expenses.Update(expense);
            await Context.SaveAsync();

            return expense;
        }
```

Repository Update

```cs
        public void Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            _dbSet.Attach(entity);
            _context.SetState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
        }
```

Comment: user.id and ModifiedByUserId  do not have same value. sometimes you don't  want to fill the ModifiedByUserId then you have to set it  with null value.

Comment: Hi Amin, i think this is the part i don't understand. I'm setting a new `ModifiedByUserId` because i have updated the entity. I'm saying that, originally the `ModifiedByUserId` was set to `X` and now it needs to be set to `Y` as a different user has edited it.

Comment: okay. no problem here . you should check your new user.id and ModifiedByUserId that they have same value or no when you want to update it. first check please

Comment: I'm not updating the `User` entity only the `Expense`. The `ModifiedByUserId` should just reference to the specified `User`. So i'm not sure why it's effecting the `User`? For example: You and Me are in the `User` table and then there's a `Expense` you originally Modified the `Expense` so  `ModifiedByUserId` is set your `User.Id`. I've now edited the `Expense` so the `ModifiedByUserId` should now be my `User.Id`. Nothing changes in the `User`, just the `Expense`.

Comment: okay. we have to way to check other conditions. first : are you sure you have real data in the user table ? (real UserId value , cuz when you  savechange it you get this error ) and second is updating the expense without new ModifiedByUserId and see it work or not. (means change on other properties no on ModifiedByUserId  )

Comment: Yep, i'm sure there Data in the table. I can update fine, if i don't update the `ModifiedByUserId` as soon as i try to update `ModifiedByUserId` i get the error.

Comment: I found a page that can help you too . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001189/entity-framework-a-referential-integrity-constraint-violation-on-many-to-many-r?rq=1

Comment: @philipxy, the solution has over 13 projects and god knows how many files, there's no simple way to just cut out that part for debugging.

Comment: @AminSaadati, yeah i've seen this post. It didn't help as i said in the OP if i set to null it works as suggested in the post, but i want to set a value not null it.

Comment: If you can't instrument your code for debugging it, you can't develop it. Anyway, give what you can. Eg the database state & what is sent to the DBMS. Eg chopping out code localizes bugs. Eg cut & paste code immediately on running & data before & after running. PS Shouldn't `public User ModifiedBy` be `public User ModifiedByUser`? Isn't `Expense.ModifiedByUserId` a string?

Comment: @philipxy,  does the naming matter from `ModifiedBy` to `ModifiedByUser`? Yes `Expense.ModifiedByUserId` is a string.

Comment: how you update the expense. please edit you post with new information. like your back end-code and everything else that can help us to find a way...

Comment: @AminSaadati, i have added code, i'm using EF code first, using repository pattern.

Comment: what is your id value? you  use GUID in there ? can you  change your to int ?and test it with int type ?

Comment: It's a string, as in the class in the OP. I'm pulling the users from Azure AD with uses a string as their ID.

Comment: Please give the table contents & all SQL code that was run for the update.

Comment: @philipxy, how can i give you that i don't generate the SQL

Comment: You could start by googling 'entity framework show sql for query that was run site:stackoverflow.com'. Etc. [Eg.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1412863/3404097)

Comment: even the SQL profile (what code you send to database)  can help us that. can you qgive us the update query that execute database

Comment: Here's the Table and some rows: https://gist.github.com/LeeStevens318/30309aaf91efc0cde97aae12b0639ca2
I have used `Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);` in my DB Context but. the update statement never prints.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. Insert images/links using edit functions. PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Please do not stop trying to output the update SQL that failed. You should also be able to access debugging your EF calls to the DBMS. Also please output the data actually in the table, not just insert statements.